# Set TableRow height using OOXML

Tags: openxml

I want to set the height of table row in OOXML 
Following is my code 
TableRow rowHeader = new TableRow();
TableRowProperties rowProperties = new TableRowProperties();
TableRowHeight tableRowheight = new TableRowHeight();
tableRowheight.Val = 100;
rowProperties.Append(tableRowheight);
rowHeader.Append(rowProperties);

But it's not working, can someone please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which API you are using, but there are two potential issues based on a reading of ISO 29500-1 (specifically sec. 17.4.80):

- The `val` attribute is in units of Twips (twentieths of a point). So your row height is 5 pts, which is very small.
- There is a second (optional) attribute for the `trHeight` element called `hRule`. It can have the values `auto`, `atLeast`, or `exactly`. If you do not specify `hRule`, then its value defaults to `auto`. `auto` means that the row height is automatically determined based on the height of the content, and the `val` attribute is igored (that's what is happening in your case).

To fix it, specify `hRule` to be `atLeast` or `exact`, then set your height appropriately, paying attention to the units.